# The term 'get-ADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm watching this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVUd9_k9C6A&t=1640s) about PowerShell. At 2:57:50, the instructor runs `Get-ADComputer`. But when I try to run the same command, I get the following error message:

```
get-ADComputer : The term 'get-ADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ get-ADComputer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-ADComputer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You need to [install RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) and then enable the "Active Directory and LDS Management Tools" feature

Comment: installing RSAT doesn't work for me. I'm not able to do it. I get an error message saying "This update is not applicable to your computer". I have Windows 10. I searched on how to fix this problem and I went through the list of suggestions, but it still doesn't work

Comment: To install specific RSAT tools on Windows 10 October 2018 Update or later
Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a set of "Features on Demand" right from Windows 10. Do not download an RSAT package from this page. Instead, just go to "Manage optional features" in Settings and click "Add a feature" to see the list of available RSAT tools.